# Launching Chrome in Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

So, I am trying to launch simple Chrome browser in Selenium 2.0

Here is my code sample:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path to\\the chromedriver.exe\\which I downloaded from\\ code.google.com");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
```

I am getting below error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port 37625
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: version info not in JSON
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Windows NT 5.1 SP3 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.89 seconds
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6b', time: '2013-08-12 15:43:19'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
at com.qspiders.seleniumpkg.ChromeDemo.main(ChromeDemo.java:16)
```

I think it is because I have Chrome version 29.0.1547.76 m

I am successfully able to launch and working on Firefox and IE. Please help me and Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I observe that you want to launch chrome driver but creating instance of Internet Explorer
Second thing, when you provide path to your chrome binary, use single forward slash.
This should work.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/..../chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I just copied wrong code from eclipse earlier..Updated now.Also, when I use double backward slash, it works very well in FF and IE. Thanks

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding, do I have to set the settings like IE in Chrome also? Like -- Tools >> Internet Options >> Security Tab >> enable/disable option  Please suggest.

Comment: @jsborn17 do you understand the second line in the error report. There is version missing in JSON. I think [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=321) is the answer for your problem